# I want to remove some characters from a string in js

Tags: javascript, python, django

I am making an Website with **Django** (Python Framework). I am passing string like this :

> Products you ordered: {"pr7":[4,"Mi Phone 8 GB RAM, 128GB
> ROM",7000],"pr8":[5,"Usha Mixer Grinder (White)",1244],"pr9":[4,"iBall
> 10000 MAh power bank (Black)",1455]}

From my `models.py` to `views.py` to my html template

But I don't want to my string to be like this

My string is:

> Products you ordered: {"pr7":[4,"Mi Phone 8 GB RAM, 128GB ROM",7000],"pr8":[5,"Usha Mixer Grinder (White)",1244],"pr9":[4,"iBall
> 10000 MAh power bank (Black)",1455]}

I want my string to be like :

> Products you ordered: Mi Phone 8 GB RAM 128GB ROM,Usha Mixer Grinder (White),iBall 10000 Mah power bank (Black)

Comment: it looks like some dictionary - how do you get it ? If it is really dictionary then format it - write some code to format it before you send it to HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can join the strings on the frontend:

```js
let obj = {"pr7":[4,"Mi Phone 8 GB RAM, 128GB ROM",7000],"pr8":[5,"Usha Mixer Grinder (White)",1244],"pr9":[4,"iBall 10000 MAh power bank (Black)",1455]}

let str = Object.values(obj).flatMap(e => e[1]).join()

console.log(str)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you keep it in model as string or some dictiony
but if you have dictionary then format it before you send it to HTML.

```
data = {"pr7":[4,"Mi Phone 8 GB RAM, 128GB ROM",7000],"pr8":[5,"Usha Mixer Grinder (White)",1244],"pr9":[4,"iBall 10000 MAh power bank (Black)",1455]}

items = [item[1] for item in data.values()]    
text = ', '.join(items)

print(text)
```

Result:

```
Mi Phone 8 GB RAM, 128GB ROM, Usha Mixer Grinder (White), iBall 10000 MAh power bank (Black)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let obj = {"pr7":[4,"Mi Phone 8 GB RAM, 128GB ROM",7000],"pr8":[5,"Usha Mixer Grinder (White)",1244],"pr9":[4,"iBall 10000 MAh power bank (Black)",1455]};
let arr= [];
for ( key in obj){
  arr.push(obj[key][1]);
}
console.log(arr.join());
```